# Determining plural forms of fictional words

Tags: plurality, grammaticality

How does one determine the **correct plurals** of **"made up" words** that have no given plural form given by its original canon source or creator?  Is it possible to determine what the "most similar" existing word would be, and mimic its own rules for making plurals?

For example, one wished to determine the plural form of *koopa*, a species from the Super Mario Bros universe, be it either *koopas* or *koopa*, would there be a way to tell by looking at similar real English words, such as "sheep" or "mouse" (which are both names of species of creatures, like the fictional word, and have special plurals)?  Or would the only way to know be to ask Shigeru Miyamoto or another source of Nintendo of America? (Please note that this is only an example, and does not itself need answering)

Comment: The author determines, according to whatever rules and purposes they may have in mind. It's not like it's covered by statute law, you know. People can do **anything** when they're making up a language.

Comment: I think this question might be more suitable on one of the other SE sites. I'm going to ask about migrating it. (I think you've asked the question well, it's just not really about English language. Maybe Writers or Linguistics can help.)

Comment: @JohnLawler I am not talking about entire languages, but rather individual, single made-up words when used in English, such as if someone invented the name of a fictional race

Comment: Yes, there are [concrete rules about these things](http://www.sci.fi/~alboin/plurals.htm). Best follow them.  I prefer the [*i*-mutation plurals of Sindarin](http://www.forodrim.org/daeron/md_plur.html) myself.

Comment: @tchrist That is an example of a specific word or language by a specific author, and is an instance of him actually defining the plural forms.  That is the opposite point of my question - To determine if this could be found or estimated in a case where the creator of a fictional word DID NOT specify the plural form.

Comment: @SouthpawHare In a sense, that word you made up will still answer to the logic John was mentioning. You invented it? Then you can choose whatever rule that word might follow. That was the point. :)

Comment: Since it is about English rather than linguistics in general, it is off-topic here. I voted to close.

Comment: @Anixx Wait, what?  It was just migrates here from the English board!  Anyway, it is not specific to the English language really, as far as I know.

Comment: @Southpaw Hare You were asking about English. If you want answers regarding other languages, you have to specify them, because this question has no general answer valid for all languages.

Comment: @Anixx No sir, I do not mention English in my question outside of my example, which should be treated as exactly that - a single, arbitrary example.  It can be applied to any language that has a concept of pluralization.  In fact, I am eager to hear about such information.

Comment: @Southpaw Hare it is language-specific. You should to mention what languages you are interested in.

Comment: @Anixx The only part specific to English is the example. Even if it wasn't the OP's original intent, it isn't hard to read the question *as written* in a language-generic fashion. Furthermore, looking at the types of answers this question is provoking it is undoubtedly a good fit here. Finally, nothing in the FAQ says that language-specific is forbidden, just that we need to be extra careful about the type of questions we accept. If the question was "how **should** we create plurals" I'd agree that it's off topic but the question seems to be asking how we naturally form the plurals.

Comment: Language-specific questions are actually allowed in the FAQ (5th item). We decided to allow them because such a question can still be linguistically relevant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Research in linguistics](http://childes.talkbank.org/topics/wugs/wugs.pdf) has shown that when English-speaking children are asked to pluralise made-up words (which fit with the phonotactic constraints of English) they use the standard productive plurals, suffixing:

- /əz/ on words with final /s, ʃ, ʧ, ʤ, z/;
- /s/ on words with an final /p, t, k, f, Ө/;
- /z/ on words with all other finals, including vowels

It seems that under normal circumstances English speakers would apply this rule to novel words, but whoever makes up the word can make up the plural as well. An example of this is the semi-jocular plurals of 'Unix' as 'Unices' and 'Unixen', instead of the predicted 'Unixes' /ˈjunɪksəz/.

For the example you give, 'koopa', the expected plural form would be 'koopas', pronounced something like /kupəz/.

Comment: That is, to say, English speakers use English plurals unless otherwise directed. Not surprising, but definitely the benchmark to measure from.

Answer (score 5):

Made up words which are used in English will follow pluralization rules that hold for other English words. See the Wikipedia entry on [Wug Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wug_test). The most reasonable plural of *koopa* is *koopas*, since most English nouns form their plurals by adding (orthographic) *-s*. If you want to take an affected air, you can call them *koopae*, by analogy with Latinate English words ending in *-a* which have a learned plural form with *-ae* (e.g., *alumna*, *alumnae*, which you might find in some brochures for women's colleges).

You couldn't get *koopa* to have another type of irregular plural (and expect people to guess you are talking about more than one kooopa), unless the singular form has the right sound pattern that will let people pick up on your game.

Comment: The Wug Test is very relevant and useful!  Thank you.

Comment: No, KOO is not a Latin letter combo, so -AE fails.  You have to follow established patterns, or devise your own in a hyperconsistent manner, or else it doesn’t work.

Comment: *Koopa* is a reasonable form for a faux Japanese loanword, though.

Comment: @tchrist cup.ae               N      1 1 GEN S F                 
cup.ae               N      1 1 LOC S F                 
cup.ae               N      1 1 DAT S F                 
cup.ae               N      1 1 NOM P F                 
cup.ae               N      1 1 VOC P F                 
cupa, cupae  N  F   [XAXFO]    veryrare
bar of an oil press (axle for millstones); axle; crooked handle (L+S);
barrel, cask, vat, tun; (esp. for wine); niche in a columbarium (for ashes);
dancing-girl; female tavern-keeper and castanet-dancer (L+S); female vintner;

Comment: But since many fewer people know anything about Latin than know that some English words in _-a_ have a plural in _-ae_, the fact that _koo_ doesn't exist in Latin is pretty irrelevant, really.